# Write the contents of the whole mongo database (contents of every collection) into JSON file using node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backup

As above, trying to get a simple backup functionality to my node app and I want to find a way to write contents of every single collection in my database to one big JSON file and store it serverside. Possible?

I'm using mongoose with node and express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `mongodump`? You just type this:

```
mongodump
```

And then it backs up all of your databases in a `dump` folder in the directory you ran it in. You can then restore it with `mongorestore`. See the [backup with mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-with-mongodump) section of the MongoDB docs for more info.

To run from `Node`, you would just call `mongodump` from a `Node` file. If this was my `main.js` file:

```
// main.js
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("mongodump", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Then I could run:

```
node main.js
```

And it will generate a `dump` folder with all my dbs in it in whatever directory I ran the command in.

Here's a gif of it on my machine:

[image: dump]

Another option, as mentioned in the comments by [Joe Drumgoole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6013145/joe-drumgoole), is `mongoexport`, which will give you the output in a human-readable format. So, if you wanted all of the documents in the `users` collection in your `todo-api` database, you would use this command:

```
mongoexport -v -d todo-api -c users -o 'todo.backup.json' --pretty
```

And that would generate a JSON file at `todo.backup.json` of the `users` collection in the `todo-api` database.

Here's what that looks like on my machine:

[image: export]

If you need to pull data from a MongoDB Atlas Cluster, here's the docs they provide (note that some of the info in here is related to my DB, you will need to use your own data):

***Data Import and Export Tools***

*Replace PASSWORD with the password for the admin user, DATABASE with the name of the database you wish to import/export to your cluster, and COLLECTION with the name of the collection you wish to import/export to your cluster. Replace FILETYPE with json or csv to specify the file type. Where applicable, replace FILENAME with the location and name of the output file (for export) or data source (for import).
NOTE: When exporting or importing CSV data, an additional --fields flag is often required. See documentation for the specific tool for additional details.*

***mongoexport  | produces a JSON or CSV export of data stored in a MongoDB instance***

Here's a few screenshots of where to find that info on the actual Atlas Culsters page:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

```
mongoexport --host Atlas-Free-Cluster-shard-0/atlas-free-cluster-shard-00-00-czaoo.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-free-cluster-shard-00-01-czaoo.mongodb.net:27017,atlas-free-cluster-shard-00-02-czaoo.mongodb.net:27017 --ssl --username taskapp --password <PASSWORD> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <DATABASE> --collection <COLLECTION> --type <FILETYPE> --out <FILENAME>
```

Comment: Or mongoexport if you want the contents in human readable format.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev how would I go about performing this from within node?

Comment: Just use the `exec()` function from `child_process`. See my update.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev although mongodump is working brilliantly, I figured out that I can't use it with Heroku as MongoDB needs to be installed in order to run these commands, which works fine locally but does not work with hosted instances I'm afraid..

Comment: @PRR Check my update. You will need to use the `Command Line Tools` of your cluster, and check out the `Data Import and Export Tools` section.

Comment: @DanielSchroederDev does running mongoexport on an atlas cluster work if running from aws ec2 with vpc peering set up? And can it be run on a snapshot instead of the live cluster?

Comment: @Sharud i’m not sure I’ve never used those services sorry.